# Can someone help me figure out how I can add the files from a existing repo I worked on with a partner to a new repo one I just made

Tags: git, repository

How do I add files from a repository I helped do a project on but don’t own to my own brand new repository, so I can retrieve all the same data myself and my partners worked on?

Just need to know what I exactly need to do to avoid conflict

Comment: clone the repo, copy the files to the new repo, and commit

Comment: Do you need the commit history of those files too?

Comment: Yes I do need the commit history @MikeKim

Comment: The key is the flag "--allow-unrelated-histories", if you search for it you can probably find explanations way better than anything I could come up with, but let me know if I can help further after you've looked and I will try

Comment: Is there a reason you can't clone the repo rather than trying to merge history from one repo into another? Please provide more details on the situation and what you trying to accomplish.